# How can i upload files

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files, upload

I have created simple component to upload files with following code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="BeetleEyeAssets">


<aura:attribute name="accept" type="List" default="['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.zip']"/>
<aura:attribute name="multiple" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<lightning:fileUpload  name="fileUploader"
                       label= "Demo Upload"
                       multiple="{!v.multiple}"
                       accept="{!v.accept}"
                       disabled="{!v.disabled}"
                       recordId="abcd"
                       onuploadfinished="{! c.handleUploadFinished }"/></aura:component>
```

Both my js and apex are empty at the moment. When i try to upload small image i get following error:

[image: error screeen]

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you actually provide a valid record Id? "abcd" isn't a real Id.

Comment: Nope i thought it is id i have to add like to html element. Where can i get valid record id?

Comment: If you're using it in recordpages use [force:hasRecordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation) . RecordId is mandatory for lightning:fileupload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"recordId" must be a valid [Salesforce ID](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004383&language=en_US&type=1). This is either a 15-character case-sensitive string or an 18-character case-insensitive string. This Id represents the record to which the file will be attached. It is a required attribute. If you just want to upload a file that is not attached to a record, you will need to use `lightning:input type="file"` instead. You can get this Id by performing a query, or from some interfaces like [`force:recordData`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData) or [`force:hasRecordId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation).

Comment: Thank you, sfdcfox, i think that is what i needed exactly :)